# IBM Websphere: Getting error for Spring AOP

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-aop

I am getting following error while booting up the server. Application has Spring as well as AspectJ classes in it.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/springframework/aop/aspectj/MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint, method=getSourceLocation()Lorg/aspectj/lang/reflect/SourceLocation;, pc=0
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)
                at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:170)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.currentJoinPoint(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:83)
```

As a first pass I gave PARENT_FIRST option for Enterprise Application

[image]

Comment: "booting up the server" means starting the Application Server JVM process? And you got that error before touching the Class loader order, correct? Which version of Spring & AspectJ? Which version of WebSphere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I'll write it here again as my first reply was deleted without any explanation though it was the correct one.

Given the exception you encounter you're likely at WAS 8.5.5.0. There's a known issue documented under APAR [PM90932](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM90932) about this. An ifix has been publisehd for this issue and you can read about it and download it from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24035220). Once the ifix is installed, the issue won't appear again.