# Swagger 2 + Spring MVC + WAS 8.5.5 throwing java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 for AOP classes

Tags: spring-mvc, websphere-8, swagger-2.0

I am new to swagger, and trying to integrate swagger2 with my Spring MVC (4.3.10 release) application which will be deployed into WAS 8.5.5. At the time of application startup, I am getting the below error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/springframework/aop/aspectj/MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint, method=getSourceLocation()Lorg/aspectj/lang/reflect/SourceLocation;, pc=0
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.lazyGetProceedingJoinPoint(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:81)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

My swagger configurations are as below,

1. Added swagger dependencies in pom.xml

   ```
   <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Added below annotations to my controller classes/operations

   ```
   @Api(value="someController", description="services API")
   @ApiOperation(value = "someOperation")`
   ```
3. Swagger reource configuration in applicationContext.xml

   ```
   <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/> 
   <mvc:resources mapping="/swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html"/>

   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>    

   <bean id="swagger2Config" class="springfox.documentation.swagger2.configuration.Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration"/>
   ```
4. SwaggerConfig class

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableSwagger2
   public class SwaggerConfig {

       @Bean
       public Docket api(){
           return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .select()
               .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
               .paths(PathSelectors.any())
               .build()
               .apiInfo(apiInfo());
       }

       private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
           return new ApiInfoBuilder()
               .title("TITLE")
               .description("Description")
               .version("1.0")
               .build();
       }
   }
   ```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599064/ibm-websphere-getting-error-for-spring-aop) by installing the ifix [PM90932](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24035220), but the error remains the same.